# react bootstrap offcanvas custom close button

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I got offcanvas working on react using bootstrap. Now I want add a custom close button but it doesn't seems to work. Please guide me on what I'm doing wrong.

```
<Offcanvas
        show={show}
        placement="bottom"
        onHide={handleClose}
        {...props}
        className={css["offcanvas-bottom"]}
      >
        <Offcanvas.Header className="p-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset new_close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          <div className={css["pop-image"]}>
            <Image
              src="https://xxxxxxx/2022030117344459.jpg"
              fluid
            />
          </div>
        </Offcanvas.Header>
        <Offcanvas.Body>
          Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you
          have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
        </Offcanvas.Body>
      </Offcanvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `onClick` in my custom button. And toggled the state by doing
`const toggleOffcanvas = () => setShow(!show)`

Example:

```
function ToggleSidebarOffcanvas(){
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggleOffcanvas = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };
return (
   <Button onClick={toggleOffcanvas}>
         Menu
    <SidebarOffcanvas show={show} toggleOffcanvas={toggleOffcanvas} />
   </Button>)
}
```

```
 function SidebarOffcanvas({ show, toggleOffcanvas }) {
  return (
    <Offcanvas className="w-25" show={show} scroll={true} backdrop={false}>
      <Offcanvas.Header
        className="p-0"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#008069",
          color: "white",
        }}
      >
        <Offcanvas.Title>
          <div
            className="d-flex align-items-end w-100 mb-2 lh-1"
          >
            <div className="p-2" onClick={toggleOffcanvas}>
              <FiArrowLeft />
            </div>
            <h5 className="ms-3">Profile </h5>
          </div>
        </Offcanvas.Title>
      </Offcanvas.Header>
      <Offcanvas.Body>
        <div >
         ...
        </div>
      </Offcanvas.Body>
    </Offcanvas>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Y.Gherbi I edited to give more context to my answer and I used a `<div />` instead of a `<button />`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue the other day and am echoing @Shlomo for the most part. Looks like you were pretty much there but missing the `onClick()`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch
      </Button>

      <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Title>Offcanvas</Offcanvas.Title>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Custom Close Button</Button>
        </Offcanvas.Header>
        <Offcanvas.Body>
          ...Your body...
        </Offcanvas.Body>
      </Offcanvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Hopefully this helps, the [Docs for React-bootstrap Offcanvas](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/offcanvas) have us infer this behaviour.